# Laravel, Artisan, нужно задать вопрос во время миграции через консоль

Tags: php, laravel, миграция, artisan

В браузерной версии приложения нет возможности зарегистрироваться, единственные пользователи - админы. Потом возможно будет. Создаем миграцию, в которой добавляем столбец admin в таблицу users

```
class UsersColumnAdmin extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('admin')->default(false);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('admin');
        });
    }
}
```

Есть самописная Artisan команда create-admin, которая спрашивает у пользователя email, password и т.п. для создания админа и создает его. Нужно сделать вызов этой команды из миграции, чтобы при накатывании миграции, позволяющей определять роль админа, система сразу и спрашивала о создании первого администратора.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(false);
    });

    Artisan::call('create-admin');
}
```

При таком подходе при попытке накатить миграцию интерфейс виснет и, вероятно, пытается общаться с пользователем в каком-то другом stdout, и ждет ответа от первого confirm'а. То есть в консоли ничего не появляется. Вопрос: как получить экземпляр текущего CLI и пробросить его в мою команду?

P.S. В отличии от seeder'ов, migration'ы абсолютно пустые и не имеют в себе интерфейса для работы с консолью.

P.P.S. Есть вероятность, что такой подход в корне не правильный, раз умные ребята из Laravel решили не включать возможность спамить что-то в консоль между миграциями. Может быть этому тогда есть разумное объяснение и как тогда разумнее всего реализовать интерфейс для моей затеи?

Comment: Для этого они и придумали сидеры чтобы забивать в базу данные после миграций: `php artisan migrate --seed`

Answer (score 1):

А зачем создавать пользователя при накатывании миграции? Миграции ведь предназначены только изменения структуры таблиц. Тем более, когда срабатывает метод `down` по логике нужно созданного админа удалить что ли?

Я думаю, что команду можно спокойно запустить именно тогда, когда это требуется( например, уже после тогда, когда нужные таблицы созданы).